# Swift iOS how to handle JSON nested array in object class?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift

I would like to create a Swift TableView for all available sizes of coffee within a specific type. With this JSON tree, how can you structure the class to create an array for the type specific sizes?

The JSON Tree is structured as follows:

```
{
 "_id": "60ba1ab72e35f2d9c786c610",
 "types": [
   {
     "_id": "60ba1a062e35f2d9c786c56d",
     "name": "Ristretto",
     "sizes": [
       "60ba18d13ca8c43196b5f606",
       "60ba3368c45ecee5d77a016b"
     ],
     "extras": [
       "60ba197c2e35f2d9c786c525"
     ]
   },
   {
     "_id": "60be1db3c45ecee5d77ad890",
     "name": "Espresso",
     "sizes": [
       "60ba3368c45ecee5d77a016b",
       "60ba33dbc45ecee5d77a01f8"
     ],
     "extras": [
       "60ba34a0c45ecee5d77a0263"
     ]
   },
   {
     "_id": "60be1eabc45ecee5d77ad960",
     "name": "Cappuccino",
     "sizes": [
       "60ba18d13ca8c43196b5f606",
       "60ba3368c45ecee5d77a016b",
       "60ba33dbc45ecee5d77a01f8"
     ],
     "extras": [
       "60ba197c2e35f2d9c786c525",
       "60ba34a0c45ecee5d77a0263"
     ]
   }
 ],
 "sizes": [
   {
     "_id": "60ba18d13ca8c43196b5f606",
     "name": "Large",
     "__v": 0
   },
   {
     "_id": "60ba3368c45ecee5d77a016b",
     "name": "Venti"
   },
   {
     "_id": "60ba33dbc45ecee5d77a01f8",
     "name": "Tall"
   }
 ],
 "extras": [
   {
     "_id": "60ba197c2e35f2d9c786c525",
     "name": "Select the amount of sugar",
     "subselections": [
       {
         "_id": "60ba194dfdd5e192e14eaa75",
         "name": "A lot"
       },
       {
         "_id": "60ba195407e1dc8a4e33b5e5",
         "name": "Normal"
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     "_id": "60ba34a0c45ecee5d77a0263",
     "name": "Select type of milk",
     "subselections": [
       {
         "_id": "611a1adeff35e4db9df19667",
         "name": "Soy"
       },
       {
         "_id": "60ba348d8c75424ac5ed259e",
         "name": "Oat"
       },
       {
         "_id": "60ba349a869d7a04642b41f4",
         "name": "Cow"
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

My classes: (I can currently load a TableView with the coffee sizes, but not the type specific sizes)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Types: Codable {
    let types: [CoffeeType]
    
    init(types: [CoffeeType]) {
        self.types = types
    }
}

class Sizes: Codable {
    let sizes: [CoffeeType]
    
    init(sizes: [CoffeeType]) {
        self.sizes = sizes
    }
}

class CoffeeType: Codable {
    let _id: String
    let name: String
    
    init(_id: String, name: String) {
        self._id = _id
        self.name = name
        
    }
}
```

The app is structured like this: HomeViewController is a TableView of Types. When you click on a Type, you transition to SelectSizeViewController, to which I have already assigned a Type through the segue. On SelectSizeViewController, I would like to display the list of specific sizes.

[image: HomeVC]
[image: SizesVC]

Comment: you can use tableview sections right? and inside that you can use tableviews if you want(that is kind of hack). from my understanding what I'm telling is you can use sections for types inside that you have again array of sizes. Populate a child tableview inside that cell there you can show the types right ?

Comment: @Jok3r, Either a child TableView or a separate TableView showing the sizes for a specific type. For example, for the type Cappuccino, a table showing: "60ba18d13ca8c43196b5f606", "60ba3368c45ecee5d77a016b", "60ba33dbc45ecee5d77a01f8".

Comment: do we need to show both In a single table view?, otherwise we can do one thing is when you click one the type cell it will redirect to a new view controller with new tableview in that cell you can show the sizes. when you perform segue you can pass the data too, if you want show everything in a single tableview then you have to use child tablview inside the cell.. based on the type array count you can set the hight too, separate tableview would be better

Comment: @Jok3r, A separate TableView is preferable. How would you set up the CoffeeType class to include the sizes array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io) to get the model this is quite helpful. you will be getting the model easily(suggestion). I think you are using the wrong model.

if your Base model struct is correct it should be something like this

```
struct Coffie: Codable {
let id: String
let types: [TypeElement]
let sizes: [Size]
let extras: [Extra]

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case types, sizes, extras
}
}
```

from here itself you can get the type and sizes with corresponded id's you can filter size values from sizes array

Comment: QuickType is great, just what I needed!

Comment: can you please accept my answer, if that helps you :) that would be great

Comment: How would you filter a TableView for size?

Comment: its not about filtering the tableview, filter the array with id then you will get the values